# How to get current Datetime and format its with date-fns?

Tags: datetime, date-fns

How to get current Datetime and result is: 
"2019-03-05T08:22:01+07:00"
I try to read docs of date-fns but i don't understand how to format current Datetime like above? I also try to format using basics javascript but result is none?

Comment: Do you want to get DateTime in date-fns or format it with date-fns?

Comment: i want to format it.

Comment: Format to ? In which format do you want to convert it to and how did you get your current DateTime as  "2019-03-05T08:22:01+07:00"?